# Android Programming Linear Layout ArrayList Integers

Tags: android, arraylist, integer, android-linearlayout

I have an arraylist of integers called numbers. How do I display these numbers horizontally and then vertically with the linear layout widget for my android app?

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<Integer> Numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Numbers.add(1);
        Numbers.add(2);
        Numbers.add(3);
        Numbers.add(4);
        Numbers.add(5);
        //Linear Layout code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: is it mandatory to do with Linear layout?

Comment: No it's not mandatory. Any way you can do it works for me

Comment: What do you mean by "horizontally then vertically"? What do you want the layout to look like? Can you provide a drawing to show what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if its mandatory create a custom table with row and column with the proper weight and repeat row wise with linear layout.
if Not mandatory then use table Layout android. it will make your job simpler.

Here I found Some old Code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dms_background" >

    <!-- User Details -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/report_title_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/forty_dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/dms_actionbar" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/report_associate_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/retailer_report"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/report_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/report_title_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp" >

        <!-- Table View -->

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <!-- Row 1 -->

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/report_salesorder_layout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/report_retailt_transaction_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_sales" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/report_retailt_transaction_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/report_retailt_transaction_image"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:text="@string/report_salesreport"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/report_retailt_transaction_text"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/devider_horizontal" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/ninty_dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/devider_vertical" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/report_salesreturn_layout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/report_partner_search_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_return" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/report_partner_search_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/report_partner_search_image"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:text="@string/report_returnreport"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/report_partner_search_text"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/devider_horizontal" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/report_paymentcollection_layout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/report_route_plan_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_payment" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/report_route_plan_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/report_route_plan_image"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:text="@string/report_payreport"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/report_route_plan_text"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/devider_horizontal" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/ninty_dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/devider_vertical" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/report_performance_layout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/report_new_partner_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_performance" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/report_new_partner_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/report_new_partner_image"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:text="@string/report_performancereport"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/report_new_partner_text"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/devider_horizontal" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <!-- Row 3 with 2 columns -->

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/report_stock_layout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/report_report_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_stock" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/report_report_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/report_report_image"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:text="@string/report_stockreport"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/report_report_text"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/devider_horizontal" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/ninty_dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/devider_vertical" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/report_report_layout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/report_empty_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_reportsasso" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/report_empty_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/report_empty_image"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                          android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:text="@string/associate_reports"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/report_empty_text"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/devider_horizontal"
                       />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```